# How to perform List of boolean expression together in recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have a `Dictinary` of `bool` and `string` which contain an operation and want to get the output in recursion how this can be achieved.

```
IDictionary<bool , string> lstIfResult = null;
```

suppose this list contains :

```
{
  { true,  "AND" },
  { false, "OR"  },
  { true,  "AND" }
}
```

My code is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstIfResult.Count(); i++)
{
    bool res = getBinaryOprResult(lstIfResult.ElementAt(i) , lstIfResult.ElementAt(i + 1));
}

private static bool getBinaryOprResult(KeyValuePair<bool, string> firstIfResult, 
                                       KeyValuePair<bool, string> secondIfResult)
{
    switch (firstIfResult.Value)
    {
        case "AND":
            return firstIfResult.Key && secondIfResult.Key;
        case "OR":
            return firstIfResult.Key || secondIfResult.Key;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

how can I recurse this function to get Key element 1 equated with 2 and then their result equated with the third.
and operation used between 1 & 2 is 1st and between their output to third is second. last key element operation will be ignored.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's *extract model* (when given a *name*, e.g. `"OR"` we return an operation to perform):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<bool, bool, bool>> s_Operations =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<bool, bool, bool>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    {  "AND", (a, b) => a && b},
    {   "OR", (a, b) => a || b},
    {  "XOR", (a, b) => a ^ b },
    { "TRUE", (a, b) => true  },
    {"FALSE", (a, b) => false },
    //TODO: add more operations, synonyms etc.
  };
```

Then you can `Aggregate` with a help of *Linq* (note, that the last operation - `"OR"` will be *ignored*):

```
using System.Linq;

...

// I've created list, but any collection which implements
// IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> will do
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<bool, string>>() {
  new KeyValuePair<bool, string>( true, "AND"),
  new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(false,  "OR"),
  new KeyValuePair<bool, string>( true,  "OR"),
};

...

// ((true && false) || true) == true
bool result = list
 .Aggregate((s, a) => new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(
    s_Operations[s.Value](s.Key, a.Key), 
    a.Value))
 .Key;
```

Comment: that's superbly brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error like "OutOfRange" becauseof lstIfResult.ElementAt(i+1) in for loop.
If you want to ignore last element , try to use

```
for (int i=0; i<lstIfResult.Count-1; i++) {
bool res = getBinaryOprResult(lstIfResult.ElementAt(i) , lstIfResult.ElementAt(i+1));
```